# Prime Number checker shows no errors but spits out an error when is executed.. how to fix this?

Tags: java

This block of code shows no errors in eclispe yet when executed it shows this:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at prime_number.main(prime_number.java:15)

Code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class prime_number {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int temp;
        boolean isPrime=true;
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter any number: ");
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        scan.close();
        
        for(int i = 0; i<num;i++) {
            temp=num%i;
            if(temp==0) {
                isPrime=false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isPrime==true) {
            System.out.println(num+" is a Prime number!");
        
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(num+" is not a Prime Number!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change i=0 to i=1.

Comment: That's a pretty clear error? You're dividing by zero on line 15, so you look on line 15, you see `temp=num%i;` and then you look at what `i` is, see it's zero, and remember that something modulo zero is definitely going to be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the first iteration of your for-loop, `i == 0`.

When it reaches the line

```
temp = num % i;
```

the program tries to divide `num` by `i` and evaluate the division remainder. Since you can't divide by zero, the program throws the error.

Answer (score 1):

Start your for loop from i=1, because when you do:

```
temp = num % i;
```

you are actually doing division by 0.

If you really want, you can start your for loop from i = 2, because i = 1 will always be factor of your number, given it is a whole number.